# How Upload file using Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, file-upload, mojolicious

I have been trying out Mojolicious web framework based on perl. And I have try to develop a full application instead of the Lite. The problem I am facing is that I am trying to upload files to server, but the below code is not working.

Please guide me what is wrong with it. Also, if the file gets uploaded then is it in public folder of the application or some place else.

Thanks in advance.

```
sub posted {
 my $self = shift;
 my $logger = $self->app->log;

 my $filetype = $self->req->param('filetype');
 my $fileuploaded = $self->req->upload('upload');

 $logger->debug("filetype: $filetype");
 $logger->debug("upload: $fileuploaded");

 return $self->render(message => 'File is not available.')
  unless ($fileuploaded);

 return $self->render(message => 'File is too big.', status => 200)
   if $self->req->is_limit_exceeded;

 # Render template "example/posted.html.ep" with message
 $self->render(message => 'Stuff Uploaded in this website.');
}
```

Comment: I do see that in the Mojolicious::Lite documentation the call to `$self->req->upload()` is wrapped in an `if()`, which means its return value is being checked before assuming there was an upload.  Doing so is the equivalent of checking the return value of open, I suppose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload multiple files using Mojolicious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602910/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-mojolicious)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(First, you need some HTML form with `method="post"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, and a `input type="file"` with `name="upload"`. Just to be sure.)

If there were no errors, `$fileuploaded` would be a `Mojo::Upload`. Then you could check its size, its headers, you could slurp it or move it, with `$fileuploaded->move_to('path/file.ext')`.

Taken from a [strange example](http://web.archive.org/web/20110218095830/http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yukikimoto/20100212/1265989676).

Comment: Thanks menozero, the HTML part is same as you have mentioned. And I have gone through the link provided, but it is developing based on the Mojolicious::Lite and full application. And in my case `$fileuploaded` is having empty value, so I am not very sure what is currently going wrong.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Thanks a lot menozero! This should be accepted as the solution by Kunal Jha. The problem from him is somewhere else...

Comment: Which library should I look at for serving files to be downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

To process uploading files you should use `$c->req->uploads`

```
post '/' => sub {
   my $c = shift;
   my @files;
   for my $file (@{$c->req->uploads('files')}) {
     my $size = $file->size;
     my $name = $file->filename;

     push @files, "$name ($size)";
     $file->move_to("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache24\\htdocs\\ProcessingFolder\\".$name);
   }
   $c->render(text => "@files");
} => 'save';
```

See full code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28605563/4632019

Answer (score -2):

You can use Mojolicious::Plugin::RenderFile

[Mojolicious::Plugin::RenderFile](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aRenderFile)

Comment: According to the documentation you linked, RenderFile is for streaming downloads, not uploads.