# Mojolicious Lite file upload

Tags: perl, upload, mojolicious-lite

I can't figure out how to upload files to the remote server in Mojolicious Lite. Here's some code, first, html form:

```
<form method='post' action='add_photo'>
    <input type="file" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and here's an add_photo testing route:

```
post '/add_photo' => sub {

    my $self = shift;
    my %params;
    my $file = $self->param('upload');
    $params{filename} = $file->filename;
    $params{filesize} = $file->size;
    $params{worknamne} = $self->param('name');
    $params{stone} = $self->param('stone');
    $params{cat} = $self->param('cat');
    $self->stash(params => \%params);
    $self->render('test');
};
```

And here's the error message I recive:

> Can't locate object method "filename" via package "name_of_file.jpg" (perhaps you forgot to load "name_of_file.jpg"?) at sv line 31

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That question was not about Mojolicious Lite. And mine is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding type goes in the form tag, not the file input:

```
<form method="post" action="add_photo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

For a detailed example, just look at: [Mojolicious::Lite #File uploads](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite#File_uploads)

Also, this question/answer has similar information:  [How Upload file using Mojolicious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152973/how-upload-file-using-mojolicious)

Comment: The link is dead.