# How to upload multiple files using Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm new to Mojolicious, trying to learn it. I'm trying to upload multiple files using form but only one file is uploaded at a time. Any suggestion?

```
#!perl -w

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::Upload;
use v5.14;

get '/' => 'page';
post '/' => sub {
   my $self = shift;
   my @files;
   for my $file ($self->req->upload('files')) {
     my $size = $file->size;
     my $name = $file->filename;

     push @files, "$name ($size)";
     $file->move_to("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache24\\htdocs\\ProcessingFolder\\".$name);
   }
   $self->render(text => "@files");
} => 'save';

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ page.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
   <form action="<%=/ProcessingFolder/%>" method="POST"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input name="files" type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" multiple="multiple">
     <button type="submit">Upload</button>
   </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found Answer. Used `uploads()` instead of `upload()` which returns Array reference.

```
#!perl -w

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::Upload;
use v5.14;

get '/' => 'page';
post '/' => sub {
   my $self = shift;
   my @files;
   for my $file (@{$self->req->uploads('files')}) {
     my $size = $file->size;
     my $name = $file->filename;

     push @files, "$name ($size)";
     $file->move_to("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache24\\htdocs\\ProcessingFolder\\".$name);
   }
   $self->render(text => "@files");
} => 'save';

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ page.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
   <form action="<%=/ProcessingFolder/%>" method="POST"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input name="files" type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" multiple="multiple">
     <button type="submit">Upload</button>
   </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a small bug in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28605563/65706)  - the variable ProcessingFolder is obsolete ...

```
#!perl -w
# install Mojolicious by : sudo -s 'curl -L cpanmin.us | perl - Mojolicious'
# run by : perl mojo-file-upload.pl daemon -m production -l http://*:8083
# point your browser @: http://127.0.0.1/upload-files
#
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::Upload;
use v5.14;

get '/' => 'upload-files-page';
get '/upload-files' => 'upload-files-page';
post '/upload-files' => sub {
   my $self = shift;
   my @files;
   for my $file (@{$self->req->uploads('files')}) {
     my $size = $file->size;
     my $name = $file->filename;

     push @files, "$name ($size)";
     $file->move_to("/tmp/".$name);
   }
   $self->render(text => "@files");
} => 'save';

app->start;

__DATA__


@@ upload-files-page.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
   <form action="/upload-files" method="POST"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input name="files" type="file" 
       enctype="multipart/form-data" multiple="multiple">
     <button type="submit">Upload</button>
   </form>
   </body>
</html>
```